# Python path: why can't pip see latest version of numpy

Tags: python, numpy, pip, python-module, scikit-image

Working inside a virtualenv, I'm trying to install scikit-image, but it fails, telling me that I need a newer (or any) version of numpy.

```
$ sudo pip install -U scikit-image
...
ImportError: You need `numpy` version 1.6 or later.
----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /Users/aps/Dropbox/experiments/build/scikit-image
```

I don't understand this, because from Python, numpy 1.7 is already on my path.

```
$ python 
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jul 31 2011, 19:30:53) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.__version__
'1.7.1'
```

What is going on - why can't the system installing scikit-image see the newest version of numpy? And how can I fix this?

The path to numpy already seems to be in my `~/.bash_profile`:

```
>>> numpy.__path__
['/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy']
>>> exit()
$ vi ~/.bash_profile
...
export PYTHONPATH=/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```

UPDATE:

numpy version 1.7 is also in the `su` path:

```
$ sudo python 
Password:
Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug  1 2013, 00:59:40) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.1 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66))] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.__version__
'1.7.1'
```

Comment: please run `pip freeze` and paste the result

Comment: Here it is (says numpy 1.7.1), thank you for looking: http://pastebin.com/Xw9SY0eS

Comment: Can you try "sudo python" and then see if numpy is still in your path?

Comment: Yes it is - see the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that all those packages are available within the `virtualenv` itself. Did you try running `pip freeze` after sourcing `bin/activate`? Using the `virtualenv` package, the only library that comes "preinstalled" by default is `distribute`, and all other dependencies must be manually added. With `venv` (built into py3k) all of your system libraries should be available directly. Which are you using?

Comment: Hi there - yes, http://pastebin.com/Xw9SY0eS is the result of running `pip freeze` inside the virtualenv.